# How do I apply a formula for each group within a row in R?

Tags: r

My dataset is:

```
CLASS     YEAR      VALUE 
A         1990        4      
A         1991        3
A         1992        7
B         1989        5
B         1990        23
B         1991        3
C         1990        7
C         1991        4
C         1992        6
```

I want to apply the CAGR formula for each class, I was trying with this code:

```
df <- df %>%
  arrange(CLASS, YEAR) %>%
  group_by(CLASS) %>%
  mutate(cagr = ((VALUE / lag(VALUE, n)) ^ (1 / n)) - 1)
```

The dataset that I am using is quite huge, the issue is that I get the first n values of the first class as N/A but it does not happen for the other classes. Therefore I think that in this way the formula takes into account the values of the class above for the first n cases which is wrong.

Comment: What is `n`? What is expected output for the data you have shared?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate year on year growth?

Comment: n is either 2/4/8 in my case, so every 2 or 4 or 8 years takes as time span

Comment: @KarthikS how would be the formula if I wanted to do it year on year?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for your CAGR:

```
library(dplyr)
library(xts)
df %>% group_by(CLASS) %>% mutate(cagr = (last(VALUE)/first(VALUE))^(1/(n()-1)) - 1)
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   CLASS [3]
  CLASS  YEAR VALUE    cagr
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A      1990     4  0.323 
2 A      1991     3  0.323 
3 A      1992     7  0.323 
4 B      1989     5 -0.225 
5 B      1990    23 -0.225 
6 B      1991     3 -0.225 
7 C      1990     7 -0.0742
8 C      1991     4 -0.0742
9 C      1992     6 -0.0742
```

Comment: n()?, the CAGR should progress every n years and change accordingly

Comment: @andriy, so n() is the last row number. Here in my above code, it's n()-1, the row number for first group, i.e. CLASS is 3, so CAGR is calculated for 3-1 that is 2 years.

Comment: @andriy, you just need to adjust the n or number of years, for YoY: try: df %>% group_by(CLASS) %>% mutate(cagr = VALUE/lag(VALUE) - 1)